# How to get unique key for any method invocation?

Tags: c#, .net, hash

I need to generate a 'hash' for any unique method invocation in my project. For example, I have method `string GetSomeString(int someInt)`. So, I need different hashes in those cases:

```
string GetSomeString(1) -- key 1
string GetSomeString(2) -- key 2
string GetSomeString(3) -- key 3
```

How to generate this kind of hashes?

UPD:
I want to log any method execution by some unique hash for each method invocation. Something like this:

```
public delegate T HelperFactoryMethod<T>();

public static LogMethodExecution<T>(HelperFactoryMethod<T> factoryMethod) where T: class
{
   string key = GetHashString(factoryMethod);
   StoreToDatabase(key);
   ...
}
```

**Result example of GetHashString() must be like :**

1. List GetSomeObjects(1, ObjectType.Simple) must be **'ListGetSomeObjects_1_ObjectType.Simple'** or something like this.
2. List GetSomeObjects(2, ObjectType.None) must be **'ListGetSomeObjects_2_ObjectType.None'** or something like this.

Comment: what if you invoke again GetSomeString(1)? Does it have to return again 1 or another value?

Comment: Could you tell us more about the ultimate goal here? I'm unsure if you're looking for a first-class function representation (delegate), to memoize the function, or something else.

Comment: You're going to need to be a bit more specific about what exactly you want this key to be like. As a trivial example, you could just return the text string "1", "2", "3", but I suspect that that's not what you want!

Comment: Yes, it have to return 1 againg

Comment: are you looking for keys or for hashes? Hashes or different often but not always, where a key is always unique.

Comment: @gyromonotron please edit your question and remove "key" since you need an hash. Anyway, your question is not very clear to me.

Comment: @gyromonotron, are you need "hash" for human reading based on param's types or param's values?

Comment: @acoolaum, I need "hash" on method name + param's values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a hash function that generete a unique key for all parameter values.
for example:

```
public string GetSomeString(int someInt)
{
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider cryptoServiceProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}{1}", "methodName", someInt));
    data = cryptoServiceProvider.ComputeHash(data);
    return Convert.ToString(data);
}
```

every unique 'methodName' and parameter will return a unique key

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I've not understand your question correctly, but why don't you use the very same someInt as hash?